# PWA Push notification permission popup not appearing on UWP webview

Tags: webview, uwp, push-notification, notifications, progressive-web-apps

I have PWA application running on Azure cloud. Application has full PWA enabled and showing the notification, when run on browser. However, when i run the same application under UWP app webview. I do not see notification permission popup. When is subscribe to notification. I get permission denied error. can some one help me that how we can show the notification popup on UWP webView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to handle the [WebView.PermissionRequested Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.permissionrequested?view=winrt-18362) in your UWP app. If you don't handle the PermissionRequested event, the WebView denies permission by default.

You could use it like this:

```
private void Mywebview_PermissionRequested(WebView sender, WebViewPermissionRequestedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (args.PermissionRequest.PermissionType == WebViewPermissionType.WebNotifications) 
        {
            args.PermissionRequest.Allow();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have this code implemented. looks like this code never get called via WebView.

Comment: @Rajalbar What's the OS version? This requires an OS version in 1607 or higher.

Comment: Version 10.0.17134 Build 17134